# Click event not working flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I have a list that as an arraylist as a dataprovider.It has an inline item renderer thet has image control. The click event doesn't work for the image ctrl.The code looks like this

```
        <s:ArrayList id="allActionsArrList">
        <fx:Object click="showList('Portlet')" source="@Embed('images/bpc1.jpg')" />
        <fx:Object click="showList('Pages')" source="@Embed('images/Tab.png')"  />
        <fx:Object click="smsClick()" source="@Embed('images/launchpad_tel.png')"  />
        <fx:Object click="logoutImg_clickHandler(event)" source="@Embed('images/logoutS.swf')"  />
    </s:ArrayList>
        <s:List id="actionStripList" bottom="0" width="100%" borderColor="black"
        borderVisible="true" contentBackgroundAlpha="0" dataProvider="{allActionsArrList}"
        useVirtualLayout="false">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer width="100%" height="40">
                <mx:Image buttonMode="true" horizontalCenter="0"
                                                  width="40" height="40" source="{data.source}" click="{data.click}"/>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Any idea.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You may do something like this:

```
<fx:Object clickHandler="{showList}" clickParams="{['Portlet']}" source="@Embed('images/bpc1.jpg')" />
<fx:Object clickHandler="{showList}" clickParams="{['Pages']}" source="@Embed('images/Tab.png')"  />
<fx:Object clickHandler="{smsClick}" clickParams="{[]}" source="@Embed('images/launchpad_tel.png')"  />
<fx:Object clickHandler="{logoutImg_clickHandler}" clickParams="{[]}" source="@Embed('images/logoutS.swf')"/>

<mx:Image buttonMode="true" horizontalCenter="0" width="40" height="40" source="{data.source}" click="data.clickHandler.apply(this, data.clickParams)"/>
```

Here you possibly should take care of `this` object ([info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply%28%29))
But I'd used the 2nd variant.

2.Another variant is to define some attribute (`id` for example) for your Object items. Then you can use `switch` statement in your inline itemRenderer and call different listeners depending on `data.id`.

Comment: What do you mean by image component i already used image control there.thanks for replying

Comment: @Naveen terribly sorry, I'm so inattentive... I've updated my answer

Comment: Hey yes I too did the same thing you mentioned in your 2nd variant,that worked.Many thanks to you